# how to add audio to existing video using FFMPEG at specific time?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have video file (.avi) that contain video of 10 minutes. 
I also have audio file (.wav) that contain 1 minute of sound.

I need to add the audio to the exist video but the audio need to start at after one minute of the video

How to do it ?

( prefer using ffmpeg if its possible )

try already this query ( 30 seconds delay )

```
-i video.avi -i audio.wav -filter_complex \"[1]adelay=30000|30000[aud];[0][aud]amix\" - c:v copy out.avi"
```

Attached the log of ffmpeg when trying to merge more then one wav:

```
ffmpeg started on 2018-01-10 at 11:14:57
Report written to "ffmpeg-20180110-111457.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg.exe -report -i "..\\merged.avi" -i "Storage\\1.wav" -i "Storage\\2.wav" -i "Storage\\3.wav" -filter_complex "adelay=30000|30000" "adelay=91000|91000" "adelay=151000|151000" -c:v copy "Storage\\ALL.AVI"
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '..\mergedVideoOnly.avi'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '\Storage\0030_0130.wav'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '\Storage\0130_0230.wav'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '\Storage\0230_0330.wav'.
Reading option '-filter_complex' ... matched as option 'filter_complex' (create a complex filtergraph) with argument 'adelay=30000|30000'.
Reading option 'adelay=91000|91000' ... matched as output url.
Reading option 'adelay=151000|151000' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option 'ALL.AVI' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Applying option filter_complex (create a complex filtergraph) with argument adelay=30000|30000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url ..\mergedVideoOnly.avi.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: ..\mergedVideoOnly.avi.
[NULL @ 042ed360] Opening '..\mergedVideoOnly.avi' for reading
[file @ 042ee300] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[avi @ 042ed360] Format avi probed with size=2048 and score=100
[avi @ 042ee500] use odml:1
[avi @ 042ed360] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 5690 bytes read:100744 seeks:4 nb_streams:1
[avi @ 042ed360] parser not found for codec scpr, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 042ed360] parser not found for codec scpr, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 042ed360] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 2.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 2.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 3.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 3.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 3.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 5.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 5.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 6.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 6.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 6.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 6.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 8.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 8.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 9.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 9.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 9.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 11.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 11.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 12.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 12.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 12.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 12.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 14.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 14.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 15.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 15.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 15.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 17.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 17.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 18.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 18.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 18.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 18.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 20.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 20.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 21.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 21.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 21.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 23.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 23.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 24.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 24.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 24.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 24.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 26.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 26.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 27.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 27.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 27.083333 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 29.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 29.916667 0.012539
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 30.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 30.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 33.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 36.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 36.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 39.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 42.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 42.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 45.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 48.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 48.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 51.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 54.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 54.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 57.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 60.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 60.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 120.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 120.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 240.000000 0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 240.000000 -0.000000
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 23.976024 0.001038
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 23.976024 0.001038
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 29.970030 0.001622
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 29.970030 0.001622
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 59.940060 0.006487
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 59.940060 0.006487
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 11.988012 0.000259
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 11.988012 0.000259
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 14.985015 0.000405
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 14.985015 0.000405
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 47.952048 0.004152
[avi @ 042ed360] rfps: 47.952048 0.004152
[avi @ 042ed360] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 105829 bytes read:175139 seeks:4 frames:15
Input #0, avi, from '..\mergedVideoOnly.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 113 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 15, 1/3: Video: scpr (SCPR / 0x52504353), rgb0, 1920x1200, 112 kb/s, 3 fps, 3 tbr, 3 tbn, 3 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input url " "\Storage\0030_0130.wav.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: " "\Storage\1.wav.
[NULL @ 03be0180] Opening '" "\Storage\1.wav' for reading
[file @ 03be0820] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[wav @ 03be0180] Format wav probed with size=2048 and score=99
[wav @ 03be0180] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 44 bytes read:65580 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:32
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:31
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:30
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:29
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:28
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:27
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:26
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:25
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:24
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:23
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:22
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:21
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:20
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:19
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:18
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:17
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:16
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:15
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:14
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:13
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:12
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:11
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:10
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:9
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:8
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:7
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:6
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:5
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:4
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:3
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:2
[wav @ 03be0180] probing stream 0 pp:1
[wav @ 03be0180] probed stream 0
[wav @ 03be0180] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 03be0180] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000 microseconds st:0
[wav @ 03be0180] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 131116 bytes read:196652 seeks:1 frames:22
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '" "\Storage\0030_0130.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:56.80, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0, 22, 1/8000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input url " "\Storage\2.wav.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: " "\Storage\2.wav.
[NULL @ 03bed760] Opening '" "\Storage\2.wav' for reading
[file @ 03bb3100] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[wav @ 03bed760] Format wav probed with size=2048 and score=99
[wav @ 03bed760] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 44 bytes read:65580 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:32
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:31
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:30
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:29
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:28
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:27
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:26
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:25
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:24
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:23
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:22
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:21
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:20
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:19
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:18
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:17
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:16
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:15
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:14
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:13
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:12
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:11
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:10
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:9
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:8
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:7
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:6
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:5
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:4
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:3
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:2
[wav @ 03bed760] probing stream 0 pp:1
[wav @ 03bed760] probed stream 0
[wav @ 03bed760] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 03bed760] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000 microseconds st:0
[wav @ 03bed760] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 131116 bytes read:196652 seeks:1 frames:22
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #2.0 : mono
Input #2, wav, from '" "\Storage\0130_0230.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:59.81, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #2:0, 22, 1/8000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: input url " "\Storage\3.wav.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: " "\Storage\3.wav.
[NULL @ 03bfeea0] Opening '" "\Storage\3.wav' for reading
[file @ 03bfe8e0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[wav @ 03bfeea0] Format wav probed with size=2048 and score=99
[wav @ 03bfeea0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 44 bytes read:65580 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:32
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:31
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:30
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:29
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:28
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:27
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:26
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:25
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:24
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:23
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:22
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:21
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:20
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:19
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:18
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:17
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:16
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:15
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:14
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:13
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:12
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:11
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:10
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:9
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:8
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:7
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:6
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:5
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:4
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:3
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:2
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probing stream 0 pp:1
[wav @ 03bfeea0] probed stream 0
[wav @ 03bfeea0] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[wav @ 03bfeea0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5120000 microseconds st:0
[wav @ 03bfeea0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 131116 bytes read:196652 seeks:1 frames:22
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #3.0 : mono
Input #3, wav, from '" "\Storage\0230_0330.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:59.81, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #3:0, 22, 1/8000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[Parsed_adelay_0 @ 03c0c460] Setting 'delays' to value '30000|30000'
Parsing a group of options: output url adelay=91000|91000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: adelay=91000|91000.
[NULL @ 03c17640] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'adelay=91000|91000'
adelay=91000|91000: Invalid argument
[AVIOContext @ 042ee400] Statistics: 175139 bytes read, 4 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 03be0900] Statistics: 196652 bytes read, 1 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 03bca7e0] Statistics: 196652 bytes read, 1 seeks
[AVIOContext @ 03bfe9a0] Statistics: 196652 bytes read, 1 seeks
```

Comment: I found how to add the audio on the start of the video ( simple Concatenate and its work ) - but i need to move the audio 1 minute foreword

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -i audio.wav -filter_complex
"[1]adelay=62000|62000[aud];[0][aud]amix" -c:v copy out.avi
```

The `adelay` delays the start of the WAV by 62000 milliseconds for all channels, assuming 2 channels in the WAV and then that is mixed with the video's audio.

---

To mix two audio files,

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -i audio1.wav -i audio2.wav -filter_complex
"[1]adelay=30000|30000[aud1];[2]adelay=90000|90000[aud2];
 [0][aud1][aud2]amix=3" -c:v copy out.avi
```

Comment: I wrote what you said - but still does not work ( 30 seconds deley )

wrote embedded in the question the query

Comment: Show the full log.

Comment: sorry ... where can i find the log ? ( i new in ffmpeg world :( )

Comment: i add the log embedded

Comment: That's for a different command, which happens to be malformed: `ffmpeg.exe -report -i "video.avi" -i "555.wav" -filter_complex "adelay=20000" - c:v copy "OUT.avi"`

Comment: now its work - but ffmpeg add the wav into two places :: 1. at the start of the video 2)after 20 seconds. 

I don't want to add it to the start - only after 20 seconds.

Comment: Because you provided only one adelay value. It should be `20000|20000`

Comment: is it possible to do it without copy to new file ? i mean to do it on the original video file

Comment: ok - but if i have 2 wav files = that the first need to start at 30 seconds delay and the second need to start at 90 seconds delay .. ( each of them has length of 10 seconds )  --  how to add them to the same video file ( new file that contain both of them ) 


i try to run loop that add them using the query above - but only one of them added

Comment: I add new ffmpeg log when i trying to marge more then one wav file - i get error

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -i "..\\merged.avi" -i "Storage\\1.wav" -i "Storage\\2.wav" -i "Storage\\3.wav" -filter_complex "[1]adelay=30000|30000[a1];[2]adelay=91000|91000[a2];[3]adelay=151000|151000[a3];[0][a1][a2][a3]amix=4" -c:v copy "Storage\\ALL.AVI"`

Comment: now, when the audio files are 30 seconds for each ( total 1 minute ) and the video is 4 minute -- then the video output is cut to 1 mimute and does not keep the original size

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how, let's see if they change the code and don't invest in companies that pay employees that would build it all.

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i 002.ogg.mp3 -i 003.ogg.mp3 -i 004.ogg.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=1000[s1];[2]adelay=2500[s2];[3]adelay=4000[s3];[s1][s2][s3]amix=3[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast video_with_audio.mp4
```

It's easy to figure out, filter_complex accepts commands as arguments sequentially and assigns variable names that can be used later in the series with the last being the command that mixes everything.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andrewhodel/a2854df02a5ab06967b5223f5b0a44b6

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure you have failed to add 'a' to 'v' testing/applying all of your search so far.

Adding audio to video is not simple as 1-2-3. Read carefully.
(a= Audio, v= Video, ta= Temporary Audio File, v.position= video file's position in mil. sec.)

If you are not able to understand below, you can simply discard your method in your project, regarding 'add a to v'. There will be not much difference doing so.

/////////////////// Big Picture ///////////////////

1. Check if 'v' has any 'a'. (out of topic).
2. If 'v' has 'a', extract 'a' from 'v', and save 'a' as 'ta'. (out of topic).
3. If 'v' does not have any 'a', collect all inserting 'a's. (out of topic).
4. Find insertion position in sec. in 'v' to insert 'a' (dynamic insertion postion upto the application). If 'a's duration exceeds the duration of the 'v' at the insertion positon, trim 'a'. (out of topic).
5. Make sure 'mix all audios' before applying to the 'v'. (out of topic).

If 'a' is not properly trimed, 'v' will play even after the 'v's duration. (out of topic).

///////////// Now back to the topic. ///////////////

Following adds [a1.aac] at v.position 0 sec., and adds [a2.m4a] at v.position 1 sec. [adelay=] must follow as [adelay=milSec.|milSec.]. [amix=2] => mixing 2 audios. Replace # with 3 in [amix=#] if you are mixing 3 audios. One of the input 'a' can be 'ta' = [Temporary Audio File] by extracting 'a' from 'v'.

ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a1.aac -i a2.m4a -filter_complex "[1]adelay=0|0[a1];[2]adelay=1000|1000[a2];[a1][a2]amix=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -y output.mp4

If adding 'a' to 'v', which does not have any 'a', pass -filter_complex "[1]adelay=v.position|v.position[a1]" -map 0:v -map "[a1]" -y output.mp4.

Please do not ask me any 'out of topic' issue.

Thanks,