# how to merge multiple audio with time offset to one audio file ?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to use FFMPEG to merege multiple audios and one audio file that will contain all of them .

Each audio file have some delay from the start - lets say that the first audio start 30 seconds after start ( the first 30 seconds will have white noise )

And the second audio file will start 90 seconds after start.

Each of the audio length is 35 seconds.

How to do it ?

Comment: Are multiple audio files to play at the same time?  Or are you just wanting to concatenate?

Comment: no, each audio file need to play in different time - just want to concatenate

file 1 need to start after 30 seconds - during 35 seconds 
file 2 need to start after 90 seconds - during 35 seconds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ffmpeg+concatenate

Comment: @Brad there is no concatenate between audio files with delay in here. i check already

Comment: Video is no different than audio for concatenate... use lavfi as a source to add any gaps.

Comment: @Brad but in all cases there is no delay that ffmpeg add as white noise between the video example

Comment: As I said, use lavfi.  You can create this white noise (or pretty much whatever noise you want) just like any other source, of whatever length you want, in your concatenate list.

Comment: Already asked and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48169031/5726027

Comment: @Mulvya this ask how to marge video and audio - my question here is only audio

Comment: That doesn't make a difference - if there is video among the inputs, don't map it.

Comment: @Mulvya but i try to do it only with audio on this way .. and i fail to create one wav file with delay

Comment: Ok, show your full command and log in Q.

Comment: have some problem with my machine so i can't copy paste the log. but in the log i see that its count not write header form the output file - Error init out stream 0:8